# how to use storyboards in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I want to reuse a `storyboad` defined in a `resourcedictionnary` and referenced in **App.xaml**

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ShowWindowStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                   >
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3"
                              Value="1" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                   >
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3"
                              Value="1" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                   >
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3"
                              Value="1" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

and here the code that gave an exception

```
Storyboard sb = (FindResource("ShowWindowStoryboard") as Storyboard).Clone();



        DoubleAnimation da0 = sb.Children[0] as DoubleAnimation;
         /* Exception here da0 is null*/
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da0, uc); 

        DoubleAnimation da1 = sb.Children[1] as DoubleAnimation;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da1, uc);

        DoubleAnimation da2 = sb.Children[2] as DoubleAnimation;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da2, uc);
        sb.Begin();
```

i have also checked that `sb.children.Count == 3` as expected.

Comment: Have you tried `sb.Children[0] as DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`?

Comment: ah yes sorry ! this an old snippet, casting to DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrame gave me the error

Comment: I applied the above Storyboard on an Image and the animation worked. Can you update the question's code after using `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`?

Comment: Also, what type of Exception are you facing exactly? ArguementException?

Comment: i have this exception

Comment: [Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[0].(2)'.

Comment: Ah, it seems like you have not added a `TransformGroup` as the `RenderTransform` of your control `uc`. Have you declared `uc` in XAML or code behind? I'm gonna post a sample of how to add a TransformGroup to RenderTransform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a TransformGroup to the RenderTransform of your `uc` control. I will be adding a TransformGroup to an Image. The same will work for your control `uc`.

**XAML**

```
<Image Source="untitled.bmp" Name="ImgDemo">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>    
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

If you have to add TransformGroup in code behind, you can use following before calling Story.Begin:

```
TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
transformGroup.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(1,1));
uc.RenderTransform = transformGroup;
```

Your `Storyboard.TargetProperty` should reflect the signature of the object that you want the storyboard to be applied to. This is why you were facing the exception. Also, you might want to change your Storyboard a little to actually see the changes on the object. Like,

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ShowWindowStoryboard">
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                               >
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3"
                          Value="0.5" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                               >
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3"
                          Value="0.5" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                               >
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3"
                          Value="0.5" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Note that the values are changed so that the animations will be noticeable. Finally, I do see that your code behind on calling the storyboard does not use proper casting. So you might wanna consider using the following,

```
 Storyboard sb = (FindResource("ShowWindowStoryboard") as Storyboard).Clone();

    DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames da0 = sb.Children[0] as DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da0, ImgDemo);

        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames da1 = sb.Children[1] as DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da1, ImgDemo);

        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames da2 = sb.Children[2] as DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da2, ImgDemo);
        sb.Begin();
```

Good luck!