# Animating UserControl

Tags: wpf, rendertransform

I've made an opacity animation using Blend on one my two `UserControls`, deleted `<UserControl.Resources>`, `<UserControl.Triggers>` and `Storyboard.TargetName` from that, placed it in `App.xaml` and it looks like:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Loaded">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" >
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

when I call it in code like this before setting the `Content` of my `ContentControl`:

```
Storyboard sb = FindResource("Loaded") as Storyboard;
sb.begin(uc1);
content.Content = uc1;

//and

Storyboard sb = FindResource("Loaded") as Storyboard;
sb.begin(uc2);
content.Content = uc2;
```

it works as expected. For the transform animation, I've deleted the `TransformGroup` as well in addition to those above and now it looks like:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Unloaded">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="-800"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

If I call it in the same way, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ''[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[3].(2)'.'
```

How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a RenderTransform to your UserControl which is similar to the Storyboard.TargetProperty which currently expects a TransformGroup with 4th child as TranslateTransform.

Add the below code to each of your two UserControls:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourUserControl"
        ...>

    <UserControl.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </UserControl.RenderTransform>
```

Comment: with that I'd another problem but `ZIndex` fixed that. Can I specify `UserControl.RenderTransform.TranslateTransform` precisely in code instead of adding those 8 lines in all `UserControls`?

Comment: following along your [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130336/how-to-use-storyboards-in-wpf/32165483#32165483), I've created a `TransformGroup`, set that as the `RenderTransform` of `UserControl` to avoid `xaml` in `UserControl`.